# How to align menu in a menu bar in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, alignment, jmenu, jmenubar

In my application,i want to keep a menu bar and menus in the menu bar and i want to align the log out button to right side like in the image below.

[image]

How can i achieve this?

Comment: You should provide more details..

Comment: the arrow shows where the log out button should go. Sorry for that.

Comment: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: aligning buttons with respect to menus can be done . You need to tell which kind of layout you are using . This link gives the various Layout Managers that are available to you http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/layoutlist.html

Comment: I'm using the free Design layout and the link you mentioned describe how it can be done when hand coding all the thing. But i'm using the Netbeans IDE.

Comment: @koli well you have to handcode . i never knew Netbeans could do UI for you . In any case i advise you to get hands dirty because selecting a proper layout will go along way in ensuring that the UI is good

Answer (score 0):

You could add `Box.createHorizontalGlue()` to your JMenuBar between Help and Logout.

Comment: As demonstrated in the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html). Read the tutorials first BEFORE posting a question.